# Server does not realize the message sent by client in Netty 4.x

Tags: java, netty

I try to learn Netty 4.x by simply implementing the following example. I have a server and a client. At a point of time, the client wants to know the current date-time and he will ask the server "What time is it?". When the server realizes the question, he will reply with the current date-time.

My implementation is as following

`TimeClientInboundHandler.java`

```
public class TimeClientInboundHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        ByteBuf byteBuf = (ByteBuf) msg;
        try {
            long currentTimeMillis = (byteBuf.readUnsignedInt() - 2208988800L) * 1000L;
            System.out.println(new Date(currentTimeMillis));
            ctx.close();
        } finally {
            byteBuf.release();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        ctx.write("What time is it?");
        ctx.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

`TimeServerInboundHandler.java`

```
public class TimeServerInboundHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        ByteBuf byteBuf = (ByteBuf) msg;
        try {
            byteBuf.readCharSequence(1024, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            System.out.println(byteBuf.toString());
        } finally {
            ((ByteBuf) msg).release();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        final ByteBuf byteBuf = ctx.alloc().buffer(4);
        byteBuf.writeInt((int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L + 2208988800L));

        final ChannelFuture f = ctx.writeAndFlush(byteBuf);
        f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                assert f == future;
                ctx.close();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

However, I did not get the expecting result. Specifically, on the server-side, the question "What time is it?" has not been printed out on console.

What wrong did I implement?

Answer (score 0):

**Reason**

There are two reasons for this problem.

Server-side cannot realize the message sent from the client-side because the message is written (from the client-side) in the wrong way. Instead of `ctx.write("What time is it?");`, we should implement as following `ctx.write(Unpooled.coppiedBuffer("What time is it?", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Furthermore, in `TimeServerInboundHandler.java`, we should remove the method `channelActive()`. This is because `channelRead()` will be never triggered, but of course `channelActive()` when the channel is active.

**Solution**

`TimeClientInboundHandler.java`

```
public class TimeClientInboundHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        ByteBuf byteBuf = (ByteBuf) msg;
        try {
            System.out.println("Client received: " + byteBuf.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            ctx.close();
        } finally {
            byteBuf.release();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("What time is it?", StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

`TimeServerInboundHandler.java`

```
public class TimeServerInboundHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        ByteBuf byteBuf = (ByteBuf) msg;
        try {
            System.out.println("Server received: " + byteBuf.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            String answer = Utils.getCurrentTime();
            ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(answer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        } finally {
            ((ByteBuf) msg).release();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER)
                .addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

`Utils.java`

```
public class Utils {
    public static String getCurrentTime() {
        long currentTimeMillis = ((System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L + 2208988800L) - 2208988800L) * 1000L;
        return new Date(currentTimeMillis).toString();
    }
}
```